# Wiremock url returning 404 on basic urlpath match, no setup errors

Tags: wiremock

[Github repo](https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/tree/createreactapp/mocks), but for ease here is my health.json stub file:

```
{
    "request": {
        "url": "/health",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "{}",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

Setup is extremely basic: I have a health.json stub file defining a very basic request. I run the following command to start up the docker container for wiremock: `docker-compose up mocks`

I then get the port from docker and hit the following url in a browser: http://localhost:49158/health

The following output is what I see from the container initialization and my attempt to hit the url:

```
@framework:~/git/habits/mocks$ docker-compose up mocks
Starting habits-mocks ... done
Attaching to habits-mocks
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 [Info] : WireMock.Net by Stef Heyenrath (https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net)
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 [Debug] : WireMock.Net server settings {
habits-mocks |   "Port": null,
habits-mocks |   "UseSSL": null,
habits-mocks |   "StartAdminInterface": true,
habits-mocks |   "ReadStaticMappings": true,
habits-mocks |   "WatchStaticMappings": false,
habits-mocks |   "WatchStaticMappingsInSubdirectories": false,
habits-mocks |   "ProxyAndRecordSettings": null,
habits-mocks |   "Urls": [
habits-mocks |     "http://*:80"
habits-mocks |   ],
habits-mocks |   "StartTimeout": 10000,
habits-mocks |   "AllowPartialMapping": false,
habits-mocks |   "AdminUsername": null,
habits-mocks |   "AdminPassword": null,
habits-mocks |   "RequestLogExpirationDuration": null,
habits-mocks |   "MaxRequestLogCount": null,
habits-mocks |   "AllowCSharpCodeMatcher": false,
habits-mocks |   "AllowBodyForAllHttpMethods": false,
habits-mocks |   "AllowOnlyDefinedHttpStatusCodeInResponse": false,
habits-mocks |   "DisableJsonBodyParsing": false,
habits-mocks |   "DisableRequestBodyDecompressing": null,
habits-mocks |   "HandleRequestsSynchronously": false,
habits-mocks |   "ThrowExceptionWhenMatcherFails": false,
habits-mocks |   "CertificateSettings": null,
habits-mocks |   "CustomCertificateDefined": false
habits-mocks | }
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 [Info] : WireMock.Net server using .NET Core 3.1
habits-mocks | Hosting environment: Production
habits-mocks | Content root path: /app/
habits-mocks | Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 [Info] : Reading Static MappingFile : '/app/__admin/mappings/health.json'
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 Press Ctrl+C to shut down
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:04:39 WireMock.Net server running
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:05:09 [Warn] : HttpStatusCode set to 404 : No matching mapping found
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:05:09 [DebugRequestResponse] : Admin[False] {
habits-mocks |   "Guid": "8767ab02-b710-4c10-8db6-826eb8563b74",
habits-mocks |   "Request": {
habits-mocks |     "ClientIP": "172.18.0.1",
habits-mocks |     "DateTime": "2022-08-13T21:05:09.2509752Z",
habits-mocks |     "Path": "/health",
habits-mocks |     "AbsolutePath": "/health",
habits-mocks |     "Url": "http://localhost:49158/health",
habits-mocks |     "AbsoluteUrl": "http://localhost:49158/health",
habits-mocks |     "ProxyUrl": null,
habits-mocks |     "Query": {},
habits-mocks |     "Method": "GET",
habits-mocks |     "Headers": {
habits-mocks |       "Connection": [
habits-mocks |         "keep-alive"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Accept": [
habits-mocks |         "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Accept-Encoding": [
habits-mocks |         "gzip, deflate"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Accept-Language": [
habits-mocks |         "en-US,en;q=0.5"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Host": [
habits-mocks |         "localhost:49158"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "User-Agent": [
habits-mocks |         "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": [
habits-mocks |         "1"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Sec-Fetch-Dest": [
habits-mocks |         "document"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Sec-Fetch-Mode": [
habits-mocks |         "navigate"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Sec-Fetch-Site": [
habits-mocks |         "none"
habits-mocks |       ],
habits-mocks |       "Sec-Fetch-User": [
habits-mocks |         "?1"
habits-mocks |       ]
habits-mocks |     },
habits-mocks |     "Cookies": null,
habits-mocks |     "Body": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsJson": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsBytes": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyEncoding": null,
habits-mocks |     "DetectedBodyType": null,
habits-mocks |     "DetectedBodyTypeFromContentType": null
habits-mocks |   },
habits-mocks |   "Response": {
habits-mocks |     "StatusCode": 404,
habits-mocks |     "Headers": {
habits-mocks |       "Content-Type": [
habits-mocks |         "application/json"
habits-mocks |       ]
habits-mocks |     },
habits-mocks |     "BodyDestination": null,
habits-mocks |     "Body": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsJson": {
habits-mocks |       "Guid": null,
habits-mocks |       "Status": "No matching mapping found"
habits-mocks |     },
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsBytes": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsFile": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyAsFileIsCached": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyOriginal": null,
habits-mocks |     "BodyEncoding": null,
habits-mocks |     "DetectedBodyType": 2,
habits-mocks |     "DetectedBodyTypeFromContentType": 0,
habits-mocks |     "FaultType": null,
habits-mocks |     "FaultPercentage": null
habits-mocks |   },
habits-mocks |   "MappingGuid": null,
habits-mocks |   "MappingTitle": null,
habits-mocks |   "RequestMatchResult": null,
habits-mocks |   "PartialMappingGuid": null,
habits-mocks |   "PartialMappingTitle": null,
habits-mocks |   "PartialRequestMatchResult": null
habits-mocks | }
habits-mocks | 08/13/2022 21:05:09 WireMock.Net server running
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping habits-mocks ... done
```

Wiremock appears to read the file fine. The url in the log matches the url in the json stub file. I don't understand what I'm missing :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend set me straight. Turns out Wiremock.net and Wiremock.org are different things, and I was using the documentation for the wrong one. Fun!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).